# Finding duplicate constants in Java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, constants

My project is not small, and consists of a lot of constants in various classes. Some of constants, like "UTF-8" are duplicated many times, so, i want to create separate class for constants only. 
Is there a way to analyze a whole project on a subject of duplicated constants, so i don't need to do it manually?

I use Intelij Idea.

Comment: CTRL+H (for me) or Edit->Find->Find in path ?

Comment: @Antoniossss i don't know every duplicated constant value or variable name, "UTF-8" is only an example

Comment: if they have different names, how can you possibly identify them as duplicate?

Comment: @agim they may have differents names, but the same string or int value

Comment: Then try searching for "public static final String" / "public static final int" and you might find all of them.. you could use regex to ignore multiple spaces between the keywords..

Comment: How about defining the constants class, then using "find and replace duplicates" on each member in turn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this plugin for that: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11016-search-string-constants

Or you can use the "Hard coded strings" inspection.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you could go ahead and use the plugin @Feedforward suggested, if you feel it would be a one-time task.
However, if you have more developers working with you, someone later might add more hard-coded values.

So its better to use a code-quality monitoring tool like [Sonar](https://www.sonarqube.org/), which will automatically give everyone a heads-up when someone adds a hard-coded value or even a bug via [Sonar's Issue tracking](https://www.sonarqube.org/features/issues-tracking/).

Also to fix your issue Sonar will automatically tell you what all classes have hard-coded and/or duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

Press `ctrl+alt+s` then search for inspections in left most column. Then enable the checkbox
"Duplicate string literal" under `Internationalization` then apply
every time you hover any constant you will find if there is the declaration in another file.